# USB contains no files after dd'ing iso

Tags: boot, usb, mount, iso, dd

Attempting to "burn" an iso (Windows 10) to my usb, I used the dd tool with commands as follows:

```
dd if=/home/user/windows10.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512 status=progress
```

After sometime, it finished and output `x records in, etc`

Browsing to the destination where it is mounted (see bottom) it turned out the directory was empty.

I unmounted and remounted the drive, it was still empty

I attempted to reformat (to ntfs again) and re-attempt the dd'ing but with the same results.

I can confirm the iso works, I used it a few days prior on the same usb, this same usb was used. (This was done in a Windows environment)

What am I missing?

```
#usb mounted with fstab
/media/user/usb-drive     /dev/sdb1     ntfs    auto  0    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off all, Windows ISO's aren't hybrid, which means that you can't use dd to write them. Hybrid ISO's contain a Master Boot Record, which tells the BIOS where to look up the file in order to load the operating system installer. Since Windows ISO files do not have that information, only Linux ISO's do (most of the time), you've got two options:

1. You copy the files directly from the ISO file to the USB drive, onto an empty FAT32 partition, and use a UEFI-based computer. UEFI works diffently, it does not use a boot record. Instead of that it uses a boot.efi file, this file is most likely to be found in the USB:/boot/efi folder, and is named bootx64.efi.
2. If your system is older and dates back to 2010-2011, you might still have a BIOS, instead of UEFI. What you want do is install UNetBootin, you can do so by typing `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`, and installing gparted, by running `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Insert your USB drive, open the Devices menu in GParted, and choose "Create partition table", then choose MBR. Create a new partition with the FAT32 filesystem, close GParted, and start UNetBootin. Select the USB, the partition, and your ISO, then open up GParted again, but without closing UNetBootin. Format the recently created FAT32 partition to NTFS, then click Next in the UNetBootin window. When it's done creating the USB, you should be able to boot from it.

Comment: thanks, I will try 1. regarding 2. I have already installed unetbootin before posting this as a last go-to resort, and after opening unetbootin I end up with a grey screen, i.e. no form objects are loaded. This has happened many an occasion before, googling this problem (that time) provided me with no solution. thanks for the response, wil report back regarding 1.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some Qt Libraries. Try install several Qt versions, then open up UNetBootin again. Otherwise I wouldn't know what causes the problem. Anyways, good luck!